# How to convert from PRTime to .NET datetime

Tags: .net, firefox, datetime

I want to convert a number that is in [PRTime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_Portable_Runtime#Time) format (a 64-bit integer representing the number of microseconds since midnight (00:00:00) 1 January 1970 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)) to a `DateTime`.

Note that this is slightly different than the usual "number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim prTimeInMillis As UInt64
prTimeInMillis = prTime/1000

Dim prDateTime As New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)
prDateTime = prDateTime.AddMilliseconds(prTimeInMillis)
```

Comment: i had to change
prDateTime.AddMilliseconds(prTimeInMillis)
to
prDateTime = prDateTime.AddMilliseconds(prTimeInMillis)
to get the correct value

Answer (score 0):

DateTime has a constructor that takes Ticks (which are 100 nanoseconds).

So take your prTime, multiply it by 10 and add it to the number of ticks representing the Epoch time and you have your conversion.

```
private static DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

private static DateTime ConvertPrTime(long time)
{
    return new DateTime(epoch.Ticks + (time*10), DateTimeKind.Utc);
}
```

Comment: 10 is for converting from the unit of microseconds (PRTime) to the unit ticks (100 nanoseconds (0.1 µs)).